# how to skip iteration of while loop in associative array means we want to execute first ,second, fourth,fifth like this?

Tags: php, associative-array

i am creating a CMS system. **if post is not published** then it will not render in html otherwise show in html. So if I fetch a associative array from database "cms" then it has some published and unpublished post. so how can i skip the unpublished posts and show only published posts in html.

i have tried if condition

```
            <!-- First Blog Post -->
            <h2 style = "color:green;">
                   <?php echo $post_title ;?></a>
            </h2>
            <p class="lead">
                 by <?php echo $post_author ;?></a>
            </p>
            <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span><?php $post_date ?></p>
            <hr>
            <img class="img-responsive" src="images/<?php echo $post_image ;?>" alt="">
            <hr>
            <p><?php echo $post_content ?></p>
            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Read More <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>

            <hr>


             **<?php } ?> **    
     **<?php } **// <!--loop ends here so that we can fetch 'n' no. of posts and displaying each post like below HTML -->

                ?>
        </div>
```

if post == published then only show it in html otherwise don't show it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if post is not published at the start of the loop. then use the continue to skip through the rest of the loop.

`while(items) {
    if(!$post->published) continue;
    // this part only runs if post is published
}`